# pass the value of aria-selected into a method

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

This maybe very simple and I have researched on here and elsewhere but I cannot seem to find a good answer to my query.

I am using Angular and have created a mat-menu-item with checkbox and name.

```
 <section  *ngFor="let group of groups;">
    <div *ngIf="group?.length > 0">
      <mat-menu-item (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <mat-checkbox checked = true 
                      (click)="myMethod(group, **<aria-checked value>**)">
          <p>{{group.name}}</p>
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-menu-item>
    </div>
  </section>
```

While I have tried using $event.checked to get the value of the mat-checkbox, it returns the same value for all the boxes. I found aria-checked is different for each section created and I would like to be able to use this value to pass it to myMethod.

Is this possible? If not, is there a way to show individual values on the created checkboxes in the ngFor?

Comment: You can have template reference like this: #checkbox (as an example). And using @ViewChild you can check if it's checked or not inside myMethod(...) in your controller/component.

Comment: @FatihErsoy, they are all showing same value. That's the problem I have with mat-checkbox.

Comment: if mat-checkbox is a group, use ViewChildren()-querylist instead of ViewChild(), and in your template, pass the index like this:  <mat-checkbox checked = true (click)="myMethod(group, index)">

Comment: @FatihErsoy can you put this is a form of an answer so I can accept. It helped me a lot

Comment: Hello, it's ok. I'm glad if I could help you and that's enough.